# How to read tabular format pdf document using python pandas?

Tags: python, csv, pandas, pdf

I want to read one pdf file which is in below format-

**data.pdf**

```
       Jan1 Jan2 Jan3 Jan4 Jan5 total
ABC    1.0  2.0  3.0  4.0  5.0  15.0
PQR    1    2    3    4    5    15
XYZ    2    2    2    2    2    10
```

I'm trying to read this file using python pandas but I didn't get any success yet. Actually I want to convert this file in csv format like below -

**output.csv**

```
names,Jan1,Jan2,Jan3,Jan4,Jan5,total
ABC,1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,15.0
PQR,1,2,3,4,5,15
XYZ,2,2,2,2,2,10
```

I already tried with [pdfminer](https://gist.github.com/zross/10298077) but didn't get any success. It's html output only gives me blank pages.

Is their any way to read pdf file using python pandas or can we convert pdf to any format and then read it using python pandas?

Comment: well pdfminer must be useful in this case! would you please provide what you have tried so far?? and sample pdf file

Answer (score 0):

If you have tabula installed then:

```
from tabula import read_pdf
data = read_pdf('data.pdf')
```

then you can print your data

```
print (df)
```

I hope this will help you !

Comment: @bikuser- tabula will not able to read column header. It will considering first row as a column header.